# How to obtain the image path/ url from a file uploaded on an openshift data dir to be stored in a postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, flask, openshift, flask-sqlalchemy

I am a self-taught programming newbie here so please bear with me. I am trying to create a site which allows users to upload their images on. With the patience of another user, I was able to get some answers as to how to create and allow users to upload their images onto the data drive on openshift. However, now I need to be able to store the image path or url onto a postgresql database (which can be called on later) so that each user will be able to keep track of the images that they have uploaded. I am currently stymied by this.
Here are the fragments of code which I feel plays a big role in answering this question:

```
    class Todo(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'todos'
        id = db.Column('todo_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        title = db.Column(db.String(60))
        text = db.Column(db.String)
        done = db.Column(db.Boolean)
        pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
        user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
        image_url = db.Column(db.String)

        def __init__(self, title, text, image_url):
            self.title = title
            self.text = text
            self.image_url = image_url
            self.done = False
            self.pub_date = datetime.utcnow()

    def allowed_file(filename):
        return '.' in filename and \
               filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']

    @app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
    def upload():
        # Get the name of the uploaded file
        file = request.files['file']
        # Check if the file is one of the allowed types/extensions
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            # Make the filename safe, remove unsupported chars
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            # Move the file form the temporal folder to
            # the upload folder we setup
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            # Redirect the user to the uploaded_file route, which
            # will basicaly show on the browser the uploaded file
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))

    @app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
    def uploaded_file(filename):
        return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                                   filename)

    @app.route('/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def new():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if not request.form['title']:
                flash('Title is required', 'error')
            elif not request.form['text']:
                flash('Text is required', 'error')
            else:
                todo = Todo(request.form['title'], request.form['text'])
                todo.user = g.user
                db.session.add(todo)
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Todo item was successfully created')
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
        return render_template('new.html')
```

The current code that I have is pieced together by various tutorials and examples.
Currently, I am trying to merge the "Todo" db, "upload" function and "new" function and am having very little success. Using the little knowledge I have, I have merely added the "image_url" portions in which will be a column that is intended to house the image path. I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could shed some light on this conundrum. Thanks a million.

Respectfully,
Max

Comment: Are you storing the files locally on the web host? If so, it might be as simple as configuring your web server to serve that static content at a specific URL and having your code generate the URLs from that information.

Comment: Ah yes, I am indeed storing on the web host. It would appear, however, that pulling the specific URL from the server wasnt as easy as I thought it would be. As for now, I'm still tinkering with the codes. I'll update here if I do find a cure to this problem. Thanks anyway!